# Temporarily disabling js/css resources

Tags: javascript, css, plone, plone-5.x

A pattern I very often used in Plone <5 to debug js or css issues was to go to `portal_javascripts` or `portal_css`, find the resource, and disable/enable it.  That way, I could get certain resources out of the way to isolate a problem, and see if the problem was affected by them being present or absent.  It was very easy and useful.

Can something similar be done in Plone 5.x?  In the resource registry it seems like you can only delete a resource, not simply disable it.  Re-adding it after deletion would probably involve more steps than just clicking a checkbox.

Comment: With JS you can disable/enable [styleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet).

Comment: Why not just use the browser tools to disable css/js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to resource registry
- click bundle name
- uncheck the "enabled" field
- click save